# Xcode doesn't give warning for unreachable code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have accidentally written a code after the return statement which can't be  reach by any code path. I was surprised to get no warning from Xcode for last line.
How do I get Xcode to show this?

```
-(int) hits{
    static int hits = 0;
    hits++;

    NSLog(@"Good Code");
    return hits ;
    NSLog(@"Bad code");
}
```

Comment: There is not question above. So im not sure what you asking. However, did you compile using `-Wunreachable-code`?

Comment: There are a great deal of warnings that are not on by default. Another good one is -Wunused-property-ivar. You can add these in the "other" warning flags in build settings.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click on the main project in the project navigator.
2. Click build settings at the top.
3. Type "warning" in the search bar in the upper right.

You should now see a list of potential issues that the compiler will check for. You can turn warnings for all of these issues on or off and even make the compiler treat the issue as an error.

**Edit:**

To expand on the comments:

1. Click on the main project in the project navigator.
2. Click build phases at the top.
3. Expand compile sources.
4. Double click on the offending file.
5. Type -Wunreachable-code in the pop-up that appears.
6. Click off to save the compiler flag.

You should now see the particular warning you were inquiring about upon building.